# Is it possible to pass environment variables to the remote ssh server when running Fabric tasks?

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

Situation: I have some Fabric-based tooling that needs to pass custom environment variables in order to ssh into remote hosts (for things like `run()`, for example). The plain vanilla ssh equivalent would be

`export VAR=foo; ssh -o SendEnv=VAR my.host.com`

I'm aware that Fabric wraps a Python ssh library called paramiko, which itself appears to support this, but my reading of the Fabric documentation has not shown me a way to pass the right values to `run()` and have them propagate to the paramiko library. Is there a way for me to achieve what I want with Fabric?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible.
The `Connection.run` method accepts `kwargs`, especially a `env` dictionary.
This collection of env vars will be passed into your SSH session.

NB: The documentation of the `Connection.run` is rather minimal. But fortunately, it wraps the `run` method of Invoke (like most other Fabric methods).
=> You can have a look at Invoke's `run` method [here](http://docs.pyinvoke.org/en/latest/api/runners.html#invoke.runners.Runner.run)